# Pattern for recording the price of Twilio phone calls

Tags: twilio

Would like to maintain a local record of the price of all the phone calls that my application makes.

Am not sure what a good pattern for this would be. It looks like the price is not available in the arguments provided during the status call back when the call is closed. I assume this means I'll need to query Twilio's servers to find the price of the call. Can I do this immediately or do I need to wait a certain amount of time for the price to populate?

Is there another pattern that would be simpler, require fewer steps, or be less error prone that I am not seeing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd recommend checking out the [Usage Records](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records) API.  These handy API's give you an easy way to get rollup data for your account, like how much your account spent yesterday, or how many outbound calls it made.

You can also set up [Usage Triggers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-triggers) to proactively notify you when threshholds are met.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it possible to get the price of a particular call in any way?

Comment: Not before you make the call.  After the call completes you can use the REST API to get the instance resource for a specific call.  That resource includes a Price property:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties

Comment: thanks Devin, but I get errors sometimes when I try to access the price of the call in the status callback, the docs also mention that the price of the call is not available immediately. I"m not sure what this means.

Comment: Calculating the price is an async activity on Twilios side so it may take several minutes for the Price property to be populated for a given call.  This is likely why its not available in the status callback.  You may have to design a scheduled job to go collect the price for completed calls every N minutes.

Comment: I know this is old, but... @DevinRader is there a way to set a notification callback for when the price does populate?